# Solace Remote VPN Bridge over SSL - Self signed certificate in certificate chain

Tags: solace

I am trying to setup a remote VPN bridge to a partner router and get this error in connection: Local SSL handshake failed: Server certificate verification failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain.

I have added the cert to the local Solace router as well as added the names to the trusted names list but still not working.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

This means that you have not installed the public cert of the root issuer of the remote Solace broker server cert.

In general, the trust chain of a SSL cert needs to be established. For example, if the entire of the server cert is like this:

```
Root > Root > Intermediate1 > Intermediate2 > Server
```

where `>` denotes "issue", and the server cert installed on the remote server (in this case a Solace broker) only has this:

```
Intermediate2 > Server
```

i.e., it contains the public certs of `Intermediate2` AND `Server`.

Then, the client (in this case the local Solace broker) needs to be able to verify the rest of the chain:

- `Root`
- `Intermediate1`

This is typically known as `ca-bundle` in most environments. "CA" stands for Certificate Authority. Unlike other OS or browsers, Solace broker does not have any defaults installed. You'll have to install those certs / certificate authorities as per steps done in https://docs.solace.com/Configuring-and-Managing/Managing-Certificate-Authorities.htm.